# Monitorar serviço com Borland Socket Server

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, socket, datasnap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em três camadas no [delphi-7](/questions/tagged/delphi-7) , utilizando o componente `TSockecConnection`.

É possível fazer o monitoramento das conexões, identificar o `IP` dos usuários conectados, bem como derrubar algum usuário?

Comment: A resposta abaixo conseguiu resolver teu problema?

Answer (score 3):

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como realizar o controle de conexões:

Para gravar quais usuários estão conectados, você precisa utilizar o evento ClientConnect do server socket e adicionar o cliente a algum objeto, lista ou dataset

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  AdicionaClienteConectado(Socket.RemoteAddress, Socket.RemotePort); 
end;
```

Da mesma forma, você utiliza o evento onCLientDisconect para remover desta lista os usuários que se desconectarem

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  RemoveClienteConectado(Socket.RemoteAddress, Socket.RemotePort); 
end;
```

E quando quiser derrubar um usuário é só forçar a desconexão do mesmo utilizando as informações que foram utilizadas para manter os dados dos usuarios conectados e dar um close na conexão

```
procedure TForm1.DerrubarCliente(const EndCliente: string;
  const PortaCliente: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections - 1 do
  begin
    if (ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[I].RemoteAddress = EndCliente) and
      (ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[I].RemotePort = PortaCliente) then
      ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[I].Close;
  end;
end;
```